# syllogism package new counter

Tags: counters

With `\syllogC`, from the syllogism package, the user includes an automatic numeration for the syllogism.

```
\syllogC{Every man is mortal} %
{Socrates is a man} %
{Socrates is mortal}
```

will produce something close to:

(S1)   Every man is mortal. Socrates is a man. Socrates is mortal.

I think users could benefit from an automatic numeration feature for each component of the syllogism:

(S1)  A.  Every man is mortal.  B. Socrates is a man. C. Socrates is mortal.

This way users could refer easily not only to the entire syllogism but to each internal part of it.

E.g.: As shown in (S1), from the premise (S1A) and the premise (S1B) derives the conclusion (S1C).

What is the best code to implement these subsidiary counters?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,
          10pt,
          ]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{syllogism}

\begin{document}
\def\preA{All men except Socrates are able to laugh}
\def\preB{Socrates is a man}
\def\Conc{Socrates is not able to laugh}

\syllogC{\preA}{\preB}{\Conc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Perhaps adding this feature would be a good suggestion to the package author

Comment: @ChristianHupfer How can I add it myself?

Comment: Honestly, the package author is the first person to be addressed for change requests. Write the suggestions to him.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use a new counter (would be difficult, perhaps)

I used another approach, replacing the list in `\@sylloc` command with a special `sylloglist` which is a clone of `enumerate`, which provides the counter anyway.

The 3rd item is a `rule`, I have to replace `\item ...` with `\item[]` there. 
The list spacing settings have been incorporated into the optional argument of `sylloglist`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt,]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{syllogism}

\newlist{sylloglist}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[sylloglist,1]{label={\Alph*},ref={(S\csname thec:syl\endcsname\Alph*)}}
\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\@syllog}{%
  \begin{list}{}
    {%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\z@}
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\z@}
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-1.5em}
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-1ex}
      \setlength{\listparindent}{\itemindent}
    }
  }{%
    \begin{sylloglist}[parsep=\z@,itemsep=\z@,leftmargin={\dimexpr\leftmargin-1.5em},itemindent=-1ex,listparindent=\itemindent]
    }{\typeout{Patching startup of list succeeded}}{\typeout{Patching startup of list failed}}

\xpatchcmd{\@syllog}{%
  \item \rule{\SY@LenRule}{\SY@HiRule}
}{%
  \item[] \rule{\SY@LenRule}{\SY@HiRule}
  }{\typeout{Patching rule item of list succeeded}}{\typeout{Patching rule item of list failed}}
\xpatchcmd{\@syllog}{%
\end{list}
}{\end{sylloglist}}{\typeout{Patching end of list succeeded}}{\typeout{Patching end of list failed}}
\makeatother




\begin{document}
\def\preA{All men except Socrates are able to laugh\label{first}}
\def\preB{Socrates is a man\label{second}}
\def\Conc{Socrates is not able to laugh\label{conclusion}}

\syllogC{\preA}{\preB}{\Conc}


\def\preA{All men except Socrates are able to laugh\label{firstnew}}
\def\preB{Socrates is a man\label{secondnew}}
\def\Conc{Socrates is not able to laugh\label{conclusionnew}}

\syllogC{\preA}{\preB}{\Conc}


In \ref{conclusion} we found that ... whereas in \ref{conclusionnew} it was shown that ...

The statement \ref{first} is the same as \ref{firstnew}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tnank you @Christian, man that was super fast! But how could you refer to each premise? My goal is to be able to refer to, say, premise A, by saying "the premise (S1A) shows that Socrates.." so the conclusion (S1C) is justified.

Comment: @user82528: I have to change some minor issue

Comment: @user82528: See the update please

Comment: That's great, thank you. Just one last detail. What if I need to refer to conclusion as "(S1C)" and not as merely "C"? The same for premise A: not "as shown in A" but "as shown in (S1A)"?

Comment: @user82528: I'll check

Comment: @user82528: Done --    `\setlist[sylloglist,1]{label={\Alph*},ref={(S\csname thec:syl\endcsname\Alph*)}}` -- the `ref=...` option changes the look of the reference format

Comment: I get a wrong result: "In S1(S1C)... S2(S2C)"...is it just me? Also, to refer to (S1) I write `\syllogC{\preA}{\preB}{\Conc}\label{zero}` and then `In \ref{zero} we found...` but it does not seem to work. Why is that?

Comment: @user82528: Have you used the new code, with the `\renewcommand{\p@sylloglisti}{...}` removed?

Comment: yes, done now and perfectly working

Answer (score 2):

The approach of the `syllogism` package is not very convincing; however, with some patches you can get what you need.

Note that the `\label` for the whole syllogism has to be placed after it like in the examples, whereas the labels for the single items must go inside them.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,
          10pt,
          ]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{syllogism}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@syllog}
  {\settowidth}
  {\setcounter{sylitem}{0}\settowidth}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@syllog}
  {\setlength{\SY@availSpace}}
  {\setcounter{sylitem}{0}\setlength{\SY@availSpace}}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\syllogC}{\stepcounter}{\refstepcounter}{}{}
\setcounter{c:syl}{1}

\newcounter{sylitem}
\renewcommand{\thesylitem}{\Alph{sylitem}\closeparenref}
\renewcommand{\p@sylitem}{\openparenref S\arabic{c:syl}}
\newcommand{\syllogD}[3]{%
  \syllogC{\sylitem #1}{\sylitem #2}{\sylitem #3}%
}
\newcommand{\sylitem}{\refstepcounter{sylitem}\thesylitem.~}
\@namedef{thec:syl}{S\the\numexpr\arabic{c:syl}-1\relax\closeparenref}
\@namedef{p@c:syl}{\openparenref}
\protected\def\openparenref#1\closeparenref{\textup{(#1)}}
\protected\def\closeparenref{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\def\preA{All men except Socrates are able to laugh}
\def\preB{Socrates is a man}
\def\Conc{Socrates is not able to laugh}

\syllogD{\preA\label{syl1A}}{\preB\label{syl1B}}{\Conc\label{syl1C}}\label{syl1}

\syllogD{\preA\label{syl2A}}{\preB\label{syl2B}}{\Conc\label{syl2C}}\label{syl2}

\ref{syl1}--\ref{syl1A}--\ref{syl1B}--\ref{syl1C}

\ref{syl2}--\ref{syl2A}--\ref{syl2B}--\ref{syl2C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An independent implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,xparse,amssymb}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { syllogism }
 {
  number         .bool_set:N       = \l_syllogism_number_bool,
  number         .default:n        = true,
  label          .tl_set:N         = \l_syllogism_label_tl,
  subnumber      .bool_set:N       = \l_syllogism_subnumber_bool,
  subnumber      .default:n        = true,
  first-premiss  .tl_set:N         = \l_syllogism_first_tl,
  first-premiss  .value_required:n = true,
  second-premiss .tl_set:N         = \l_syllogism_second_tl,
  second-premiss .value_required:n = true,
  conclusion     .tl_set:N         = \l_syllogism_concl_tl,
  conclusion     .value_required:n = true,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\sylref}{m}{\textup{(\ref{#1})}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\syllogism}{m}
 {
  \setcounter{syllogismitem}{0}
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { syllogism } { #1 }
  \bool_if:NT \l_syllogism_number_bool
   {
    \refstepcounter{syllogism}
    \tl_if_blank:VF \l_syllogism_label_tl { \label { \l_syllogism_label_tl } }
    (\thesyllogism)\qquad
   }
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  \bool_if:NT \l_syllogism_subnumber_bool
   {
    \refstepcounter{syllogismitem}
    \thesyllogismitem.~
   }
  \l_syllogism_first_tl
  \\
  \bool_if:NT \l_syllogism_subnumber_bool
   {
    \refstepcounter{syllogismitem}
    \thesyllogismitem.~
   }
  \l_syllogism_second_tl
  \\
  \midrule
  \bool_if:NT \l_syllogism_subnumber_bool
   {
    \refstepcounter{syllogismitem}
    \thesyllogismitem.~
   }
  \l_syllogism_concl_tl \qquad $\therefore$
  \end{tabular}
  \group_end:
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\openparenref}{u\closeparenref}{\textup{(#1)}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\closeparenref}{}{}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{syllogism}
\renewcommand{\thesyllogism}{S\arabic{syllogism}\closeparenref}
\renewcommand{\p@syllogism}{\openparenref}
\newcounter{syllogismitem}
\renewcommand{\thesyllogismitem}{\Alph{syllogismitem}\closeparenref}
\renewcommand{\p@syllogismitem}{\openparenref S\arabic{syllogism}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\syllogism{
  number,
  label=syl1,
  subnumber,
  first-premiss={All men except Socrates are able to laugh\label{syl1A}},
  second-premiss={Socrates is a man\label{syl1B}},
  conclusion={Socrates is not able to laugh\label{syl1C}},
}

\bigskip

\syllogism{
  number,
  label=syl2,
  first-premiss={Mus syllaba est},
  second-premiss={Syllaba autem caseum non rodit},
  conclusion={Ergo mus caseum non rodit},
}

\bigskip

\syllogism{
  first-premiss={Mus syllaba est},
  second-premiss={Mus autem caseum rodit},
  conclusion={Ergo syllaba caseum rodit},
}

\bigskip

References:

\ref{syl1}--\ref{syl1A}--\ref{syl1B}--\ref{syl1C}

\ref{syl2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A variant that allows to break overlong items in the syllogism. A new key `maxwidth` has been added (default value `\linewidth`). The label sticks in the margin of the items if they have to be split across lines (when subnumbering is activated, of course).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,xparse,amssymb,varwidth,showframe}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { syllogism }
 {
  number         .bool_set:N       = \l_syllogism_number_bool,
  number         .default:n        = true,
  label          .tl_set:N         = \l_syllogism_label_tl,
  subnumber      .bool_set:N       = \l_syllogism_subnumber_bool,
  subnumber      .default:n        = true,
  first-premiss  .tl_set:N         = \l_syllogism_first_tl,
  first-premiss  .value_required:n = true,
  second-premiss .tl_set:N         = \l_syllogism_second_tl,
  second-premiss .value_required:n = true,
  conclusion     .tl_set:N         = \l_syllogism_concl_tl,
  conclusion     .value_required:n = true,
  maxwidth       .dim_set:N        = \l_syllogism_maxwidth_dim
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\syllogism}{m}
 {
  \setcounter{syllogismitem}{0}
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { syllogism } { maxwidth=\linewidth, #1 }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_syllogism_concl_tl { \unskip \nolinebreak\qquad $\therefore$ }
  \noindent
  \bool_if:NT \l_syllogism_number_bool
   {
    \refstepcounter{syllogism}
    \tl_if_blank:VF \l_syllogism_label_tl { \label { \l_syllogism_label_tl } }
    \makebox[3em][l]{(\thesyllogism)}
   }
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  \syllogism_make_text:V \l_syllogism_first_tl
  \\
  \syllogism_make_text:V \l_syllogism_second_tl
  \\
  \midrule
  \syllogism_make_text:V \l_syllogism_concl_tl
  \end{tabular}
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \syllogism_make_text:n
 {
  \begin{varwidth}
   {
    \dim_eval:n
     {
      \l_syllogism_maxwidth_dim
      \bool_if:NT \l_syllogism_number_bool { - 3em }
      - \tabcolsep
     }
   }
  \bool_if:NT \l_syllogism_subnumber_bool
   {
    \leftskip=1.5em
    \refstepcounter{syllogismitem}
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[1.5em][l]{\thesyllogismitem.}}
   }
  \ignorespaces
  #1
  \end{varwidth}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \syllogism_make_text:n { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\openparenref}{u\closeparenref}{\textup{(#1)}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\closeparenref}{}{}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{syllogism}
\renewcommand{\thesyllogism}{S\arabic{syllogism}\closeparenref}
\renewcommand{\p@syllogism}{\openparenref}
\newcounter{syllogismitem}
\renewcommand{\thesyllogismitem}{\Alph{syllogismitem}\closeparenref}
\renewcommand{\p@syllogismitem}{\openparenref S\arabic{syllogism}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\syllogism{
  number,
  label=syl1,
  subnumber,
  first-premiss={All men except Socrates are able to laugh\label{syl1A}},
  second-premiss={Socrates is a man\label{syl1B}},
  conclusion={Socrates is not able to laugh\label{syl1C}},
}

\bigskip

\syllogism{
  number,
  label=syl2,
  first-premiss={Mus syllaba est},
  second-premiss={Syllaba autem caseum non rodit},
  conclusion={Ergo mus caseum non rodit},
}

\bigskip

\syllogism{
  first-premiss={Mus syllaba est},
  second-premiss={Mus autem caseum rodit},
  conclusion={Ergo syllaba caseum rodit},
}

\bigskip

\syllogism{
  number,
  label=syl3,
  subnumber,
  first-premiss={
    All men except Socrates are able to laugh
    All men except Socrates are able to laugh
    All men except Socrates are able to laugh
    All men except Socrates are able to laugh\label{syl3A}
  },
  second-premiss={Socrates is a man\label{syl3B}},
  conclusion={Socrates is not able to laugh\label{syl3C}},
}

\bigskip

References:

\ref{syl1}--\ref{syl1A}--\ref{syl1B}--\ref{syl1C}

\ref{syl2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. `The approach of the syllogism package is not very convincing`: why? Also how to get (S1)-(S1A)-(S1B).. instead of just S1-S1A-S1B...? I really need the brackets :-)

Comment: @user82528 Define `\newcommand{\sylref}[1]{\textup{(\ref{#1})}}` and use `\sylref` instead of `\ref`. I looked at the macros and they seem much more complicated than necessary.

Comment: I know this is silly of me at least, but would it possible to keep the basic `\ref`command? With the `\sylref` I end up losing the TeXmaker automatic completion while writing and this really slows things down..

Comment: @user82528 It's possible; check now

Comment: I love the independent implementation, it's fireworks!

Comment: the implementation seems not to tolerate long blocks of text as premises or conclusion without overfull warnings. Why is that? How to correct?

Comment: @user82528 Now they allow line breaks. Note that my macro doesn't produce overfull boxes, contrary to the original ones. ;-)

Comment: sorry no idea how to manipulate your code... how to indent text in premises and conclusion as in lists?

Comment: @user82528 Is it nicer now?

Comment: well I find it far more readable, don't you agree? Thank you. Where do I find documentation on how to read your code? Is that LaTeX3?

Comment: @user82528 Yes, `texdoc interface3`